# Import of python package `pyunpack` throws invalid syntax error

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-2.x

I'm using python 2.7 and pip 20.0.2 and have intalled `paramiko pyunpack patool tqdm` packages in my virtual env.
But the below line throws a syntax error. Why would that be?

`from pyunpack import Archive`

`File "/home/../.myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyunpack/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>`

`from easyprocess import EasyProcess`

`File "/home/../.myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 61`

`cmd: Union[List[str], str],`

```
   ^
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pyunpack`](https://github.com/ponty/pyunpack) requires python >= 3.7 not python 2 so you should use python 3. As for the specific traceback, python 2 does not support type hints using that syntax

Comment: Looking at this https://pypi.org/project/pyunpack/ it says 2.7 is supported?

Comment: @KR29 It's clear from github (and indeed the code) that python 2 is not supported with the current version, this needs to be fixed on pypi

Comment: I'm using the pyunpack 0.2.2. https://github.com/ponty/pyunpack/tree/0.2.2 This was all working before  and recently something broke

Comment: Ah yes that version supported 2.7, but not the current version on the master branch. `EasyProcess` also requires 3.7 with the master branch

Comment: Yes it looks like the easyprocess that it adds is 1.1 which requires 3.7. So I need to force easyprocess to take the 0.2.5 version